# Is there a way to alter Powershell's environment path based on the current working directory?

Tags: powershell

So I have a code repository with some utility scripts under a Scripts folder. Whenever I want to run the utility script, I have to type:

```
./scripts/someScript.ps1 someParam
```

Is there a way for me to set the env:path so I only need to type:

```
someScript someParam
```

But only when the working directory is part of my local repository? So for example it would work when I'm in:

```
c:\code\project1
c:\code\project1\source
```

but not in

```
c:\code
c:\code\project2
```

Thanks!

Comment: To do this I'm pretty sure you need to extend(proxy function) `Set-Location` with custom code that checks the current path `$pwd` and modifies the sessions enviroment variable if you're inside the specific folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @graimer mentions you can [create a proxy function](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/video-shay-levy-and-kirk-munro-leveraging-proxy-functions-in-powershell/) to override the default Set-Location (and cd) behavior.   However an easier approach might be to just create some aliases.  I do this to make sure I get a specific version of msbuild e.g.

```
New-Alias msbuild4 c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0....\msbuild.exe
```

Comment: Thanks! A proxy function seems really neat but an alias only takes 2 seconds to write, so I'll go with that for now.